# Set max features in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

I have created a pipeline using a LogReg classifier and I want to restrict the maximum number of features selected by the Lasso but can't see how to do this anywhere. I know about Scikit-Learns SelectFromModel Function but that would require me to use a lasso/ridge regression and so I would need to turn off the penalty term in my classifier. However, my best model uses LibLinear which requires a penalty term to be set in the classifier parameters.

```
model = Pipeline(steps=[
('preprocessor',preprocessor),
('classifier',LogisticRegression())
```

Comment: sorry i really lost you, can you clarify properly the question at hand, you are using LogisticRegression() and you want to use the X most useful terms?

Comment: Yes that is correct